# Window Opened Event in JApplet

Tags: java, japplet

I made a gui extends `JFrame` and now i convert it to `JApplet` and i have a problem with some methods/events.

1. I used Window Opened Event in `JFrame`

   ```
   private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       P1.setVisible(true);
       P2.setVisible(false);
       jProgressBar1.setVisible(false);
       jLabel15.setVisible(false);
   }
   ```

   and i don't know how to call it from `JApplet` and
2. On button click i used `close()` method

   ```
   private void close() {
        WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
   }
   ```

But Applet doesn't recognize "this".
Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"I made a gui extends `JFrame` and now i convert it to `JApplet`"*  Why?  Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I am using JApplet because i want to run it to web..How can i do that with JFrame?

Comment: *"..i want to run it to web.."*  It depends on exactly what you mean by that, but look at [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: I thought that this is for JApplet only..

Comment: Well, now you know different.  I'd highly recommend launching the frame direct from a link using JWS.  It will make it much easier, and get around the fact that Chrome - and soon FF and IE will have no support for embedded applets at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I'll give it a try...